# Log two places simultaneously - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

How can we log a single event at two different places? say STDOUT and some other log file?

Comment: did u give a try to logger.info

Comment: @Dave i am creating a _logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log") and then for logging i am using _logger.info("my log message"). Is there anyway i can create _logger for two different locations? I can create two different variable and do .info to both individually but that doesn't seem a good way to me.

Comment: what do you mean by two different locations exactly

Comment: i mean two different files. say file1.log and file2.log or file.log and STDOUT

Comment: check if answer i posted helps you out...